# Django REST API - How to stay "logged in" on refresh?

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

I am using DJANGO Rest API and an AngularJS client and I cannot figure out how to remain logged in when I refresh the page! (Django does this when they render html on their back-end stuff)...

I have authtoken and my default auth classes are:

```
'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'
```

I have ng-Cookies in AngularJS and I've tried a few things I've read online about keeping headers and such but nothing has seemed to work. :(

Ideas?

Comment: how do you login with angular? session or token?

Comment: this was my stupidity. ;) I was setting the cookie 'csrftoken' which would overwrite what Django was sending me; therefore each time I would try to refresh the page, I would be rejected as there wasn't a proper token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this sounds silly but ensure the cookie that you set to hold your token is not labeled 'csrftoken' :).

Comment: how do we do that?